# Element not using the right Color from styling sheet

Tags: html, css, angular

My HTML element is styled using '''[ngStyle]="{'background-color': project.colorIndicator?.colorIndicatorColor}''' And in the global styling sheet, Yellow is set to #FFCB14, however when the project color indicator is set to yellow, the Color on the site shows up as default yellow. [Styling global](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9enGp.png) [Current Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RN86.png) [target yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBCdq.png)

Comment: Did you set the color indicator to `yellow` or `var(--Yellow)`?

Answer (score 1):

Either throw a !important on the end or use a more comprehensive selector

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`[ngStyle]="project.colorIndicator ? {background-color': colorIndicatorColor} : {}`